# Create a pop-up page with its own URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, vue.js

I'm developing an application which includes some pages, will open up when a menu item is clicked. Even though it opens up looking like a pop-up page, it should have its own URL and is a separate page. Similar to how Trello’s cards open as pop-up but has its own URL too.

how can i do that and need to know about the technology behind this stuff ??

Trello's card pop-up images attached below.

[before click the trello's card link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8OuI.png)

[trello card open as pop-up with its own URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgfsv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use vue-router. Your cards will be displayed in some sub-route and your "board" or home page will be the root page.

Here's the get [started for vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html), and the working code below:

```js
const Card = { template: '#card-template' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/card/:id', component: Card },
]
const router = new VueRouter({routes})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: "#app",
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.6.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<script id="card-template" type="text/x-custom-template">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">Card {{$route.params.id}}
    <a href="#/">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>


<div id="app">
  <a href="#/card/1" class="card">Card 1</a>
  <a href="#/card/2" class="card">Card 2</a>
  <router-view>To be replaced</router-view>
</div>


<style>
.card {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal {
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
</style>
```

P.S. In this example I'm using hashbang urls which indicates using # in the path, but you can make it work with standard urls too.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to build is a single page application or SPA.

A normal web aplication works like this:

1. The client makes a request to the server.
2. The server returns a page asociated with that url.
3. The client renders the page.
4. The user interacts with the page, possibly navigating to another page, and starting from 1.

In a SPA, the workflow is diferent. The server returns a page which contains all the logic for the app (or at least all the logic to retreive more logic as needed). When you navigate to a different url, instead of sending a request to the server, the SPA will decide what to do on this new url (render a new page, open a modal, etc).

Framworks to build SPAs include AngujarJS, Angular (aka Angular2 or Angular4) and ReactJS.

In particular, if you choose Angular. You could use [this](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal) to display a modal on a URL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but i need to render that requested page looking like a pop-up page, like trello card.

Comment: Yes, i ve checked your example, we can use this for display a modal in a url, but need to view previous page through modal background dark spaces.. like second image link on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The most simpelest way of achieving this is by first setting a popup background container right after your `<body>` tag

```
div.popup-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Inside this element you can create your popup window

```
div.popup-element {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 4em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
}
```

Use as follow:

```
<div class="popup-bg">
  <div class="popup-element">
    <h2>My settings popup<h2>
    <p>Bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To display the element you call a ONCLICK event with DOM listener to change `div.popup-bg` to `display: block;`

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('popup-bg').style.display = 'block';">Open popup</a>
```

Comment: how can i give its own url for each popup?

Comment: With this method you can't, except for `#something-something`. But why would you want to?